# Angular ui.bootstrap.timepicker 1 hour behind

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, meanjs, angular-bootstrap

Hi im playing with angular ui time picker 
http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

put when i use it, my date is 1 hour behind, how do i change this and why ?

JS

```
 $scope.dateStart = new Date();
    $scope.dateStart.setUTCHours(7);
    $scope.dateStart.setUTCMinutes(0);
```

HTML

```
                                <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label">Start</label>
                                <timepicker data-ng-model="dateStart"  hour-step="1" minute-step="15" show-meridian="false"></timepicker>
                             </span>
                                </p>
                            </div>
```

when i run it show clock 08:00 but i set it to 07:00 as you can see
and when i set it to eg. 10:00 on gui {{dateStart}} shows "2015-01-20T09:00:17.382Z" and not T10 :/

Comment: Are you sure you are accounting for the timezone correctly? I can't tell from your code. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_setutchours.asp

Answer (score 0):

You need to add filter to output date, like this:

```
{{dateStart | date:'shortTime' }}
```